# Substituting function into standard Maclaurin series

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I understand that when using standard Maclaurin series (e.g. $e^x = 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + ...$ , we can substitute $x$ with other functions such as $z = x^2$ to transform the standard Maclaurin series into $e^{x^2} = 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2!} + ...$ I would like to ask why doesn't this require a $\frac{dz}{dx} = 2x$ component in the expansion since the standard Maclaurin series are derived from differentiation of the original term. Thank you!

Comment: While cumbersome, you can try to take a couple of derivatives of $e^{x^2}$ and see for yourself what the coefficients will be.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! In this case, the first-order derivative would be $2xe^{x^2}$, which would cancel out the first $x$ term when x = 0 and I realize it's probably not the best example. If it was $e^{2x}$ instead, would that still be an issue since the first-order derivative is $2e^{2x}$? Thanks!

Comment: If you try it out with $e^{2x}$ it is easier to take a couple of derivatives and then you can see that there is no need for an extra factor $2$ (derivative of 2x). What you do have to realize is that the Interval Of Convergence may change with these kind of substitutions. The e-power does not have those restrictions, but other functions who have a power series representation, may have.

Comment: Ahh, I think I see it now, for the $x^2$ example as well, the first $x$ term is cancelled too. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple:

$$f'(x)=\frac d{dx}e^{x^2}=2xe^{x^2}$$ and $f'(0)=0$ ! [Not a factorial]

---

You can try the full computation of the Taylor development of $e^{x^2}$ and that of $e^x$ where you substitute $x$ for $x^2$ and you will see a perfect match. This is because the Taylor development is unique.

---

**Extra note.**

The derivatives of $e^{x^2}$ are in close relation to the Hermite polynomials (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials). These are alternatively even and odd, and this is why you will not find odd powers in the Taylor development.

Answer (score 1):

(edit2)
As Yves has kindly pointed out, the intuition below is not true for substitution into Taylor series.

---

Having a shot at the question generally,

Degree-n taylor polynomials centred at $0$, of $f(x)$ and $f(g(x))$ is given by $f(x) \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{f^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k $ and $f(g(x)) \approx \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(f\circ{g})^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$

Thus, for a direct substitution of $x=g(x)$ into the degree-n Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$ to be equal to the degree-n Taylor polynomial of $f(g(x))$. We need to be able to express $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(f\circ{g})^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ in the form of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{h^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$, implying $g(0)=0$. Thus, I think direct substitution of $g(x)$ in n-degree Taylor polynomials will yield the expected n-degree Taylor expansion for the composite function, only if $g(0)=0$.

---

(edit)
For OP's example, let $f(x)=e^x, g(x)=x^2, f(g(x))=e^{x^2}$ and $p(x)$ be n-degree Taylor polynomial of $f(x)$, given by $1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\dotsb+\frac{x_n}{n!}$. Considering the first few terms of $f(g(x))$, we have

$f(g(x))\approx f(g(0))+xg'(0)f'(g(0))+\frac{1}{2}\,x^2(g'(0)^2f''(g(0))+g''(0)f'(g(0)))$
$=f(0)+0+\frac{1}{2}\,x^2(2f'(0))$
$=1+x^2=p(x^2)$ where $n=2$

A counterexample where a substitution into a n-degree Taylor polynomial does not yield the expected n-degree Taylor polynomial of the composite function, would be to let $g(x)=x+1, f(g(x))=e^{x+1}$. Considering the same few terms of $f(g(x))$ above, we have
$f(1)+x(1)f'(1)=e+ex$. However, a direct substitution for $n=2$ yields $p(x+1) = 1+(x+1)$

The substitution in the first example where $g(0)=0$ reduces $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(f\circ{g})^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$ to the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{h^{(k)}(0)}{k!}x^k$. Thus, there is equality between $p(g(x))$ and similar n-degree Taylor expansion of $f(g(x))$. The second substitution does not do so.

Comment: This does not explain at all why the terms of odd degree are missing. Shame on the OP.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've added in OP's examples and attempted to explain them.

Comment: Your counter example is wrong. $e+ex+\cdots=e\cdot e^x=e^{x+1}$. The composition of Taylor series always works.

Comment: The counter example shows an instance when substituting into a Taylor series does not yield the Taylor composition of the composite function. Yes $e^{x+1}\approx e+ex+\dotsb$, but that is not equal to $p(x+1)=1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2/2+\dotsb$, where $p(x)$ is the Maclaurin series of $e^x$.

Comment: This is where you are wrong. $1+(x+1)+(x+1)^2/2+\cdots$ is indeed the Taylor development of $e^{x+1}$. For instance, the constant term is $1+1+1/2+1/3!+\cdots$ which is of course $e$, and matches $e^{0+1}$. You can check the other terms.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I brainfarted there...
Is the intuition more valid if we consider Taylor polynomials instead of series?

Comment: No, Taylor developments, finite or not, are unique.